# Python plotly axis has duplicated dates,

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly graph where the axis is dates made like this

```
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y='supply')
fig.update_layout(xaxis_tickformat = '%b %-d, %Y')
```

originally the axis labels had a time row 00:00 and 12:00 but I got rid of that because the date data doesn't have times in.

now the problem is there's 2 ticks for every date. I guess this is because it's using a datetime axis but there's no times. Getting rid of the time labels didn't really solve anything. how can I get 1 tick per date?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the number of ticks, you can use `nticks()`, which will let you select the number of ticks you want to display. Below is an example to demonstrate this... similar what you might have.

```
>> df
    supply  date
0   75  2022-04-09
1   75  2022-04-09
2   75  2022-04-10
3   75  2022-04-10
4   78  2022-04-11
5   78  2022-04-11
6   81  2022-04-12
7   81  2022-04-12
8   81  2022-04-13
9   81  2022-04-13
```

Code

```
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y='supply')
fig.update_layout(xaxis_tickformat = '%b %-d, %Y')
fig.update_xaxes(nticks=5)
```

**Plot**
BEFORE

[image]

AFTER

[image]